# Как лучше делать контроль

Tags: php, mysql

Привет Всем. 
У меня есть такая задача и не знаю как лучшее, то-есть надо создать модуль для сборке компьютеров из детали которые хранятся в БД и сделать совместимость, что-бы не получилось что на мамке AMD можно было ставить проц. Intel или что-то другое... и сижу уже пару недель и думаю как это организовать, сделать совместимость по категорий или на каждую детали, и что использовать в качестве сравнителя. 
БД на MySQL и PHP.
Спасибо.

Comment: ответь себе на такой вопрос - несовместимость идет по производителям или по деталям? и тогда станет легче

Comment: отсечением делай. в частности по мамкам-процам - сокет, мамка - память тип памяти, частота и кол-во слотов, а так-же макс объем наверное

Comment: несовместимость по деталям

Answer (score 1):

Задача станет типовой, если посмотреть на неё как на ф-ю "Рекомендуемые":

Чел. покупает материнскую плату AMD и ему рекомендуют процессоры AMD. Если он упёртый и хочет непременно Intel, пусть купит, конечно - вдруг это для другого компа.

Ещё вариант, прописать четкий сценарий: что сначала, что потом. Начать с материнки, потом проц, потом память, и т.д.

Технически - создать таблицу односторонних связей:

```
id; title; options
1 ; "материнки AMD такие-то" ; id_проц_AMD1,id_проц_AMD2, .. id_ram_1;
2 ; "материнки AMD другие" ; id_проц_AMD5,id_проц_AMD6, .. id_ram_11;
3 ; "материнки Intel раз" ; id_проц_Intel1,id_проц_Intel2, .. id_ram_11;
```

И в товарах, например, конкретной материнке - поле "рекомендуемые" содержит этот id рекомендуемого набора.

Comment: На такой вариант как если клиент хочет только комплектующие или комп в сборке я подумал, в начале у него спросить и ставить галочку.

Answer (score 0):

При добавлении товара указывать сокет, после выбора материнской платы иcкать процессоры `WHERE`socket`= motherboard.socket`